# Is there any command line interface for Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to access ORM layer to create new users or dummy data while the app is running. There is a feature like this in Rails. Does it possible for Spring Boot Application?

Comment: use `curl` and `post` new users through API while the app is running

Comment: a suggestion: add a breakpoint in at an appropriate place and run some code that calles ORM with dummy data.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - Currently, I am working with this method, but, I think it is not safe.

Comment: Unless you're hitting breakpoints on a production server, it should be perfectly safe to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Spring does not provide any command line interfaces like that. Spring gives lot of features to plugin your implementations to create such dummy data. 
Spring boot - with jdbc starter just picks sqls inside classpath with name schema.sql and data.sql. These names can be also overriden.

You can also register ApplicationListeners as below.

```
public class EndpointsListener implements ApplicationListener {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
            ApplicationContext applicationContext = ((ContextRefreshedEvent) event).getApplicationContext();
            YourDaoRepository repo = applicationContext.getBean(YourDaoRepository.class);
             // Do what ever u want here.
        }
    }
}
```

To populate data or do any other kind of initialization you can use these.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need command line access, maybe [CRaSH](http://www.crashub.org/) is something you could take a look at. But beware, [it's deprecated and will be removed with Spring Boot 2.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-remote-shell.html).

If you want to do something directly after the bean context is created, try out the [CommandLineRunner](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner) interface.